# Simple sematic action destroys the result in Spirit X3

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-x3, semantic-actions

I have this Spirit X3 parser

```
    auto xyz_def = 
        x3::omit[x3::int_] >> x3::eol >> 
        (x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - x3::eol)]) >> x3::eol >>
        (*(chemical::parser::atom >> x3::eol)
    ;
```

Which parses, with no problem something like this

```
2
Comment
H 1.2 3.2 4.5
C 1.1 9.1 8.5
```

Now I want to use (instead of completely ignoring) the first integer as a hint to help build the vector (from the Kleen*).
To do that I do:

```
    auto xyz_def = 
        x3::omit[x3::int_[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx).reserve(x3::_attr(ctx));})]] >> x3::eol >> 
        (x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - x3::eol)]) >> x3::eol >>
        (*(chemical::parser::atom >> x3::eol)
    ;
```

However, when I do this, although the parsing function succeed, I have an empty result. This is particularly mysterious because the sematic action, in principle, has no salient side effect.

I found this workaround, which was to introduce *all* the sematic actions explicitly.

```
    auto xyz_def = 
        x3::omit[x3::int_[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx).reserve(x3::_attr(ctx));})]] >> x3::eol >> 
        (x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - x3::eol)])[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx).comment = x3::_attr(ctx);})] >> x3::eol >>
        (*(chemical::parser::atom >> x3::eol)[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx).atoms.insert(end(x3::_val(ctx).atoms), x3::_attr(ctx));})])
    ;
```

This is obviously an overkill.
**Why is it that when I add just one semantic actions in the first element, I have to add sematic actions for all?**

I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858425/discarding-parsed-result-after-semantic-action?noredirect=1#comment98405631_55858425), but I was using the wrong version of Spirit (Qi) and I am also using attributes now instead of capturing lambdas, so that I can define self-contained rules.

The full code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/M7X-_s), can be pasted in https://wandbox.org/

Answer (score 1):

By accident, while reading the code of `rule` `/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/detail/rule.hpp` I noticed that it has a third template parameter called "force attributes".

```
    template <typename ID, typename Attribute = unused_type, bool force_attribute = false>
    struct rule;
```

Well, it turns out that putting `true` made the expected result to work.

```
    x3::rule<class xyz_, chemical::xyz, true> const xyz = "xyz";
```

(before it was `x3::rule<class xyz_, chemical::xyz> const xyz = "xyz";`)